# Google cloud, curl through ssh gives `Connection refused` for service listening on port

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, port, firewall

I'm trying to connect to a service running on a google cloud platform VM from the ssh terminal.

The running process is listening on 7076 as shown here:

```
ced@instance-1:~$ sudo ss -ltn
State        Recv-Q       Send-Q             Local Address:Port              Peer Address:Port       Process       
LISTEN       0            4096               127.0.0.53%lo:53                     0.0.0.0:*                        
LISTEN       0            128                      0.0.0.0:22                     0.0.0.0:*                        
LISTEN       0            128                         [::]:22                        [::]:*                        
LISTEN       0            1024                       [::1]:7076                      [::]:*
```

I also have the following firewall rule that allows internal connection:

```
Name                    Type     Targets      Filters                 Protocols/ports  
default-allow-internal  Ingress  Apply to all IP ranges: 10.128.0.0/9 tcp:0-65535, udp:0-65535
```

When using the command:

```
    curl -X POST  --data '{"action": "benchmark"}'  localhost:7076
```

The response is:

```
    curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 7076: Connection refused
```

As I understand:

- [::1]:7076 means my service is listening to connection on local host only
- I connected through ssh and then used curl, which is an internal connection (ie: from localhost)

Therefor I don't see why I cannot connect.

Comment: Try **curl -6 http://[::1]:7076**. If that works, then your application is only listening on IPv6 localhost.

Comment: @JohnHanley that seems to be the case. Could you give an answer explaining how one can spot that etc for future readers and myself ?

Comment: Your command **sudo ss -ltn** shows **[::1]:7076**. The address **::1** is IPv6 localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Hanley is mention, your application is listening on [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Addressing), you can identified with the local address and port referred as "[::1]:7076".

```
The loopback address 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 is abbreviated to ::1.
```

To used the IPv6 with a curl is necesary to run as the following esplained on the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) page.

- -6: This option is to used only IPv6 protocol.
- -g: This option switches off the "URL globbing parser". When you set this option, you can specify URLs that contain the letters {}[] without having them being interpreted by curl itself.